# Retrieve IMEI number of device from own android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-security, imei

I tried with TelephonyManager giving access for required permissions "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" but still not able to retrieve it. Is there no way we can do so? CUrrently developing using java and testing on android 11.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. I have seen it but still there must be a way to retrieve IMEI as some of the paid sdk i am using in my own phone is able to detect my device IMEI even when my phone is Android 11.